# How do I create a perfect intersect between my PC and Macbook Pro when my Mac is plugged in to an alternate input on my monitor?

Tags: windows-7, osx-mavericks, synergy

My Macbook Pro is to the left of my PC's monitor.

It is also connected to my monitor via DisplayPort. My PC is connected via DVI-D.

If I change the source on my monitor to DisplayPort, I can work entirely on my Mac - as I like to do at times. I can move my mouse from one Mac desktop to another in this mode - and a little too far to the right will cause it to disappear on to my PC desktop being displayed on the inactive input, which is expected.

The problem is, when I want to use my Mac and PC together, to get to my Mac desktop I have to pass a 'hidden' desktop with my mouse, and the same again if I want to go back - increasing the journey.

How do others solve this problem? Is there a way that I can create a perfect intersect with my Mac when my display is switched to DVI-D?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a "hacky" solution, but.. unplug the DisplayPort cable when the display is switched to DVI-D?

An alternative would be to leave the monitor on the Mac, keep working on the Mac, and use remote desktop into the PC instead of Synergy.

Comment: I would upvote this for the response to a difficult question, but I don't have enough rep' yet. This is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know if you'll find the answer you're looking for. The Mac apparently creates the second desktop - or the extension of the desktop - when it sees that its DisplayPort output is connected to your monitor. Your monitor, even if it is switched to its DVI-D input, is still presenting a "connection" to the Mac's DP port. If you don't want the Mac to create the second desktop you have to break that connection, one way or another - that's my analysis, anyway.